# Assigning strings to a shared multiprocessing pool array

Tags: python, arrays, multiprocessing, shared-memory, pool

I'm trying to assign strings to a shared multiprocessing array variable using the following code, which results in the error: `RuntimeError: SynchronizedArray
objects should only be shared between processes through inheritance`. Firstly, I'm wondering if there is any way to pass the array as an argument since it seems to not like that...

```
import multiprocessing
from itertools import repeat
import ctypes

list_1 = ["bob", "joe", "fred"]
list_index = [0, 1, 2]

def function_1(index_num, name, shared_array):
    shared_array[index_num] = name

if __name__ == "__main__":
    pool = multiprocessing.Pool(processes = 3)
    shared_arr = multiprocessing.Array(ctypes.c_wchar_p, ["", "", ""])
    pool.starmap(function_1, zip(list_index, list_1, repeat(shared_arr, 3)))
    pool.close()
    pool.join()
```

Secondly, I tried moving the shared array outside of being an argument and outside `name == main` so it could be inherited. Here is that new code:

```
import multiprocessing
import ctypes

list_1 = ["bob", "joe", "fred"]
list_index = [0, 1, 2]
shared_arr = multiprocessing.Array(ctypes.c_wchar_p, ["", "", ""])

def function_1(index_num, name):
    shared_arr[index_num] = name

if __name__ == "__main__":
    pool = multiprocessing.Pool(processes = 3)
    pool.starmap(function_1, zip(list_index, list_1))
    pool.close()
    pool.join()
    print(shared_arr[0])
```

With this new code, the strings seems to enter into the shared variable just fine, but when I go to print out a value using `print(shared_arr[0])` it gives the error `ValueError: character U+162c640 is not in range [U+0000; U+10ffff]`. I've been reading other stackoverflow posts saying to use `ctypes.c_wchar_p` as the type of array (which I did), so I don't understand why it doesn't like the data type being used.

Thank you!

Comment: `shared` + `multiprocessing` in one sentence sounds like a big red flag,, you might want to send messages from all other processes to the 1 that will modify a non-shared array

Comment: Isn't the whole point of `multiprocessing.Array()` to be able to share data between processes using shared memory though? How would you implement the solution you're referring to? I'm not quite sure I follow

Comment: yes it is. no one said it's a good idea to use it if you can avoid it though :)